# Why Nginx return error when include Naxsi rules?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to secure my Nginx server by using Naxsi but when I try to restart Nginx I get this error:

```
Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] "LearningMode" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules:4
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Here is my nginx.conf file

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
   worker_connections 768;
}

http {
   sendfile              on;

   tcp_nopush            on;
   tcp_nodelay           on;

   keepalive_timeout     65;
   types_hash_max_size   2048;

   include               /etc/nginx/mime.types;
   default_type          application/octet-stream;

   access_log            /var/log/nginx/access.log;
   error_log             /var/log/nginx/error.log;

   gzip                  on;
   gzip_disable          "msie6";
   gzip_types            text/plain
                         text/css
                         application/json
                         application/x-javascript
                         text/xml
                         application/xml
                         application/xml+rss
                         text/javascript;

   include               /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;
   include               /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
   include               /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

`naxsi_core.rules` is the file with default naxsi's rules. `conf.d` is empty so there are no rules icluded and inside `sites-enabled` is my default server conf file:

```
server {
 listen            8090;
 server_name       example.com;
 root              /home/test/unicorn/public;
 include           /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules;
}
```

Here I'm including `naxsi.rules` which is the default naxsi rules file:

```
LearningMode;
SecRulesEnabled;
#SecRulesDisabled;
DeniedUrl "/RequestDenied";

## check rules
CheckRule "$SQL >= 8" BLOCK;
CheckRule "$RFI >= 8" BLOCK;
CheckRule "$TRAVERSAL >= 4" BLOCK;
CheckRule "$EVADE >= 4" BLOCK;
CheckRule "$XSS >= 8" BLOCK;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your file "naxsi.rules" is not included in the right block.

You need to move it to a location block :

```
location / {
      include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules;
}
```